# A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' Even though it's not a wildcard

Tags: php, ajax, backbone.js, cors, slim

Hello I am experiencing a strange bug with PHP and marionette.js. I have a frontend made of marionette.js (extending backbone.js) which needs to do CORS calls to my backend API running slim on another URL. I've overriden backbone's sync function to allow withCredentials and stuff :

```
var proxiedSync = Backbone.sync;

  Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
    options || (options = {});

    if (!options.crossDomain) {
      options.crossDomain = true;
    }

    if (!options.xhrFields) {
      options.xhrFields = {withCredentials:true};
    }

    return proxiedSync(method, model, options);
  };
```

In my Slim 3.5 backend I have this middleware setup for my CORS headers :

```
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
$response = $next($req, $res);
return $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'false')->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4000')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization, Session')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD');});
```

Now I have the current response in chrome debug tool :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load xxxxx. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

However when I look at the Network tab and examine the Request Headers, I can clearly see that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not a wildcard, but 'http://localhost:4000' :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 09 Sep 2016 17:35:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/7.0.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.0
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization, Session
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Content-Length: 1130
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**EDIT 1 : HERE'S MY OPTIONS ROUTE**

Here is my Options Route in slim :

```
$app->options('/{routes:.+}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $response;
});
```

**EDIT 2 : PRE FLIGHT RESPONSE AND REQUEST**

Ok so here is a quick update with the preflight response Request Headers :

```
OPTIONS /devsea/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:4000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:4000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
```

Here is the response headers to the pre-flight request :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 16 Sep 2016 00:49:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win64) PHP/5.6.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.16
Set-Cookie: UserSession=aemsvqf9b7u2c4isdhocq4mre7; expires=Fri, 16-Sep-2016 01:49:38 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization, Session
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: What your route responds with does not match what the pre-flight request responds with.

Comment: @geggleto any idea where I'd modify this?

Comment: Look for an options route in Slim

Comment: @geggleto It's already setup, I've updated my post you can see. It might be related to something else?

Comment: no something doesn't make sense... look through all your code to find the '*'

Comment: Show us the pre-flight request and response in addition to the actual request and response of the API call.

Comment: @EmileBergeron updated with your question, do you see anything strange?

Comment: pre-flight should return `204 No Content`, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Also, we need to see the request, the actual `POST` request.

Answer (score 0):

So I know it makes absolutely no sense. But after rebooting my development machine, everything started to work. Sorry for the troubles everyone, maybe apache needed a reboot or something.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I've set the origin correctly, but the wildcard error keeps appearing. I'm using node, nginx, and pm2. I'm wondering if the headers are cached somewhere. It was working for me before, but now it's not.